# MySQL Unknown table in field list

Tags: mysql

I have a specific mysql (version 5) query:

```
SELECT finding.ID, finding.Material,
(SELECT CASE
            WHEN 'Metal' IN (
                SELECT m2.Value FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := ParentID FROM material WHERE ID = _id) AS ParentID, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl 
                FROM (SELECT @r := finding.Material, @l := 0) vars, material m WHERE @r <> 0) m1 JOIN material m2 ON m1._id = m2.ID) 
            THEN 'Met' 
            ELSE '' 
        END AS result) 
AS 'finding.MaterialGroup',finding.Description FROM finding;
```

The query searches for data from the "finding" table. The table contains a column "Material". This column references another table, which is constructed according to the child-parent principle.

The purpose of the complicated subquery is to list all the parents of the Material column so that I can then check for a specific value in it.

The problem: I get the error "Unknown table 'finding' in field list". So I can´t use the code: "@r := finding.Material".
In the subquery, the finding table may not be recognized because it is not in the scope of the subquery.

If I try following code, it works.

```
SELECT finding.ID, finding.Material,
(SELECT CASE
            WHEN 'Metal' IN (
                SELECT m2.Value FROM (SELECT @r AS _id, (SELECT @r := ParentID FROM material WHERE ID = _id) AS ParentID, @l := @l + 1 AS lvl 
                FROM (SELECT @r := 3, @l := 0) vars, material m WHERE @r <> 0) m1 JOIN material m2 ON m1._id = m2.ID) 
            THEN 'Met' 
            ELSE '' 
        END AS result) 
AS 'finding.MaterialGroup',finding.Description FROM finding;
```

Does somebody now a solution?

Here is code to set up example tables, if you want to try by you own:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `finding` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` text,
  `Material` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

INSERT INTO finding
(id, `description`, material)
VALUES
(1, 'Test1', 1),
(2, 'Test2', 2),
(3, 'Test3', 4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `material` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ParentID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;

INSERT INTO material
(id, `value`, ParentID)
VALUES
(1, 'Metal', 0),
(2, 'Tree', 1),
(3, 'Apple', 2),
(4, 'Table', 0);
```

Here's what I expect the outcome to be:
[image]

Comment: `.. WHERE .. IN (SELECT .. @variable ..) ..` is non-deterministic. Using `@variable` in more than one subquery and/or nesting level is non-deterministic.

Comment: *Here's what I expect the outcome to be* Explain in details how does each its line is produced.

Comment: CAUTION:  Asigning variables (eg, @r) in `SELECTs` is deprecated.  There might be a "windowing function" to achieve the desired goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5 recursive subqueries are not available so my idea was to write recursive function. But they are not available too. But you can write a function calling recursive procedure, so:

Query:

```
SELECT ID, Material, case when find_metal(material) = 1 then 'Met' END AS result 
FROM finding;
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_metal(i_id int) RETURNS int
  
BEGIN
    DECLARE res int;
    CALL get_metal(i_id, res);
    RETURN res;
END;
```

Recursive procedure called by function:

```
create procedure get_metal (i_id int, out ret int)
begin
  
  declare v_value varchar(50);
  declare v_parent_id int;
  set max_sp_recursion_depth=50;

  select value, parentid into v_value, v_parent_id from material where id = i_id;

  if (v_value = 'Metal') then 
    set ret = 1;
  elseif v_parent_id = 0 then 
     set ret = 0;
  else 
    call get_metal(v_parent_id, ret);
  end if;
end;
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FohdOJ4Q)